# analyse webserver execution time

Tags: apache-httpd, php, nginx, webserver

I have 2 VMs which are  almost the same, except for hostname and things that shouldn't matter (as far as I know).

On these VMs I run **nginx/1.14.2** as proxy with an **Apache/2.4.38** webserver behind it including **php-7.4.28** and **mysql-5.7.37**.

I even copied the config-files from php and mysql, nginx and apache vhost from one to another machine.

On both VMs the webserver is running fine if I call a site with `phpinfo();` content or a static html file.
On both VMs an onlineshop-system (openmage) is running fine.

But on one VM another onlineshop-system (shopware6) is extremely slow (= response time up to 60 sec). On the other VM it runs fine.

Since I use the same versions on the same operating system (debian/buster) with the same configuration, I don't know what causes the problem.

Any ideas or suggestions?

If needed, I can provide any further configuration details.

Thank you!

Update:

I had a look at differnt things:

- cpu-time: 102 ms
- wall-clock time: 90 secs
- turning off mysql made no difference
- avoiding the proxy made no difference
- cli-execution takes very long time too

vmstat from non working machine:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0   1792 2250052 381472 1175636    0    0   100   407  162  337  2  0 98  0  0
 0  0   1792 2250140 381472 1175636    0    0     0     0  105  134  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0   1792 2250140 381472 1175636    0    0     0     0   73  101  0  0 100  0  0
```

vmstat from working machine:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0   1792 1709948 321864 1311356    0    0    14    68  151  262  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0   1792 1709908 321864 1311356    0    0     0     0  287  482  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0   1792 1709908 321864 1311356    0    0     0     0  282  493  0  1 100  0  0
```

Comment: Did you do some edits? For example point php to own database?

Comment: Yes, both instances use their own database, which is at this point still empty. So there is nothing to read or write. Even the "Start installation"-Page takes very long to load.
I used this to analyse php execution time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php
Turns out it is 120 ms - so php doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Check with `vmstat` the load of the machines

Comment: update the original posts with the vmstat output

Comment: please execute `vmstat 1 3`, this you show is average from the machine start

Comment: I updated the post - hopefully this was correct? ---
I also tested the script without mysql in the background and still - execution time is ~90 secs.
So mysql doesn't seem to be the problem either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134663/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-ulbiopro).

Comment: How do you calculate the response time? Do you access both VMs from a test-host, or do you access each of them from the other? How is name resolution done, and does it work correctly?  suppose you did not copy the same network settings to both vhosts?

Comment: Responsetime is calculated in the script on the server. I checked network configuration - both VMs are in the same network running on the same host. dns is handled by the same dns-server. I did not copy the network settings - correct. I doubt a networking issue, since static files are served fine and very fast.

Comment: @gerhardd.
THANK YOU! That's it. The network configuration was incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

As @gerhardd. mentioned correctly: I didn't copy the network setting. So there could be a possible difference, and it was!

On the slow server a search domain was configured. And the installed php-script includes a part where it tries to connect to a mysql-server with the domain: "_placeholder.test".
Since "_placeholder.test" is not a FQDN it appends the search domain suffix. The search domain dns-records provide a wildcard entry which resolves to an actual server. This server dropped forbidden requests instead of rejecting them. So the script had to wait for a timeout and continued afterwards.

On the fast server, there was no search domain configured. So it couldn't find a server to "_placeholder.test" and didn't wait for any response. The script executed immediately afterwards.

Comment: Great! Have fun, and check in here from time to time, to help others.